Need capl script to get the value of particular byte of a first CAN message which is being sent periodically over CAN bus
Need CAPL script to get the value of particular byte of a first CAN message which is being sent periodically over CAN bus
I tried to set the local flag to some other value and added if condition to store the very first byte to the same local flag
This is not working as expected, the byte of first message is not being stored in the local variable, random value from subsequent message is getting stored.
Need solution here
code:
 variables 
{ 
    int value =-1 
} 

on Message msg1 

{ 

if (this.id == 0x11) { if (value == -1) { value = this.byte(23); 

} 
} 
} 


What did you observe in the debugger? I.e. how often is something assigned to value and when? How does the rest of your code look like? The very first byte is not at positiom 23.

I am sending CANFD message periodically which is of 64 bytes, in that particular byte of very first message I need to capture on message event.
Only once the partular byte position will be assigned to 'value', that is when the message starts flowing on the bus. That's what the expectation from the code I shared above, but its capturing some random value of subsequent messages.
To be clear I am not capturing the first byte of message. Capturing the particular byte from the very first message which is being increment on particular byte position on each transmission and sending periodically.

Again: What did you observe in the debugger? I.e. how often is something assigned to value and when? How does the rest of your code look like?

variables 
{ 
  int value =-1;
} 

// Use the message id here if you are only interested in one frame, 
// otherwise use * instead if you want to handle all frames
// If you are using a message id at the same time another part uses *, the 
// defined message will not trigger in the * part
on Message 0x11
{ 
  if(value == -1)
    {
      // Try to use the same variable type (byte in this case)
      // Otherwise try to cast the value gotten to correct data variable
      // type as seen below (int)
      value = (int) this.byte(23);
    } 
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
